# Replacing $C_c^\infty$ by $H_0^1$ in the definition of weak subsolution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-operators

Consider the elliptic operator
$$Lu=-\sum_{i,j} (a^{ij}u_{x_i})_{x_j},$$
where $a^{ij}\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $a^{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j\geq\lambda |\xi|^2$ for all $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x\in\Omega$.

> **Definition.** A function $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ is said to be a *weak subsolution* if
>   $$\int_\Omega\sum _{i,j}a^{ij}u_{x_i}\phi_{x_j} \leq 0, \quad\forall\ \phi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega),\;\phi\geq 0.$$

[Page 9 of this book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=1Mcc-xi_4ZMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Second%20Order%20Elliptic%20Equations%20and%20Elliptic%20Systems&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAGoVChMI5I7K36DeyAIVzJKQCh3_FAMB#v=onepage&q=Second%20Order%20Elliptic%20Equations%20and%20Elliptic%20Systems&f=false) says that, if $u$ is a weak subsolution, then the inequality above is also valid for any $\phi\in H_0^1(\Omega),\ \phi\geq 0$.

This is, probably, an elementary fact about density, but how can we prove it?

If $\phi\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ and $\phi\geq 0$, then there is a sequence $(\phi^n)$ in $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ such that $\phi^n\geq 0$ and $\phi^n\to\phi$ in $H_0^1(\Omega)$, right? So,

$$\int_\Omega\sum _{i,j}a^{ij}u_{x_i}\phi^n_{x_j} \leq 0, \quad\forall\ n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

How can we justify the passage to the limit?

Answer (score 1):

As a function of $\phi$, your last displayed equation's LHS is a bounded linear functional, so the weak convergence in the $H^1$ norm is enough to pass to limit!!

Comment: TagCharacters, could you elaborate more?

Comment: @Pedro Suppose your elliptic operator is simply the Laplacian. Then you want to pass to limit in $\int_\Omega \sum_i u_{x_i}\phi_{x_i}^n = \int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla \phi^n \leq 0$. But $F(\phi^n):= \int_\Omega \nabla u \nabla \phi^n$ satisfies $F:H^1_0 \to \mathbb{R}$ and is bounded. Therefore, since $\phi^n \to \phi$ in $H^1_0$, it converges weakly in $H^1_0$, and recalling defn. of weak convergence, you can pass to the limit.